# Access django model outside of django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to access my model outside of django like so:

```
import django
import sys
import os
#from django.db import models
from companies.models import Entity

class MyClass():

    sys.path.append("mypath")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "en_settings")
    django.setup()

    urls = Entity.objects.values_list('twitter_url', flat=True)[:10]
    for u in urls:
        print u
```

I get the error:

> No module named companies.models

How can I access my model?  Thanks

Comment: you need to add your pythonpath before you import ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley Isn't that done in my settings with this value: BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

Answer (score 0):

Jordan Beasley was correct in the comments.  The import of the model has to happen after django_setup

```
import django
import sys
import os


class MyClass():

    sys.path.append("mypath")
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "en_settings")
    django.setup()
    from companies.models import Entity
    urls = Entity.objects.values_list('twitter_url', flat=True)[:10]
    for u in urls:
        print u
```